# How to make a vertical scrollview Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I am trying to make a vertical scrollview in Xamarin(for iOS). The scroll view scrolls up and down vertically how it is supposed to but when I populate it with buttons they are added horizontally. I am new to Xamarin and the only example they give is a horizontal scrollview it seems. Thanks in advance here is my code :

```
    nfloat h = 50.0f;
    nfloat w = 150.0f;
    nfloat padding = 10.0f;

    scrollView = new UIScrollView
        {

            Frame = new CGRect(0, 100, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height),
            ContentSize = new CGSize(View.Frame.Width,View.Frame.Height*3),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
        };
    //This is in a separate area and there are a few more of these blocks of code
    var button = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
                        button.SetTitle(ln, UIControlState.Normal);
                        button.Frame = new CGRect(padding * (i + 1) + (i * w), padding, w, h);
                        button.TouchUpInside += Button2TouchUpInside;
                        scrollView.AddSubview(button);
                        buttons.Add(button);
    //then finally
    View.AddSubview(scrollView);
```

Comment: Swap the x and y in your CGRect.... `padding, padding * (i + 1) + (i * w)`